# Biblatex multiple author annotations

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, highlighting

I'm highlighting certain authors in biblatex using the annotation feature:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@MISC{test,
  AUTHOR    = {Last1, First1 and Last2, First2 and Last3, First3},
  AUTHOR+an = {2=highlight},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I want to add another annotation e.g. `highlightB` which highlights in e.g. bold and color red which can be used as an alternative to the already existing `highlight` annotation.

I fideled around with an additional `\ifitemannotation{highlightB}` in both `\mkbibnamegiven` and `\mkbibnamefamily` but couldn't get it to work properly. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to nest the tests for the annotations. Note that I use `\mkbibcompletename` to format the complete name at once instead of redefining the macros for all name parts.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {\ifitemannotation{highlightB}
       {\textcolor{red}{#1}}
       {#1}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{example1,
  title     = {Mock Title},
  author    = {Albert Einstein},
  author+an = {1=highlight},
  year      = {2019},
}
@misc{example2,
  title     = {Mock Turtle},
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  author+an = {1=highlightB},
  year      = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,example1,example2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Einstein in bold, Elk in red]

Comment: Ah! that's what I was missing. Thanks a lot