Highlight corresponding author in bibliography
Is there a way to indicate one the corresponding author in biblatex? I've seen some
posts that highlight the same author for all entries, but what I need is something slightly different and I couldn't adapt those solutions to my need.
Perhaps the bib entry could include a field which specifies the author and then that author is made bold when the bibliography is printed.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
  author = {Author, A. and Writer W., Corresponding C.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
  corresponder = {Corresponding},
}
@article{key2,
  author = {Author, A. and Writer W., Corresponding C.},
  year = {2010},
  title = {Second Title},
  journal = {Second Journal},
  corresponder = {Writer},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{key, key2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}

I've tried this implementation based on the answers here, but \savefield doesn't seem to work.

\newcommand{\makecoressbold}{%
  \DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
    \savefield{corresponder}{\corresponder}
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}
    {%
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\namepartfamily}{\corresponder}{\mkbibbold{\namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni}}{\namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni}}
      %
    }{\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
        {\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\namepartfamily}{\corresponder}{\mkbibbold{\addcomma\addspace \namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni}}{\addcomma\addspace \namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni}}
        {\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\namepartfamily}{\corresponder}{\mkbibbold{\addcomma\addspace \namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni\addcomma\isdot}}{\addcomma\addspace \namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni\addcomma\isdot}}%
      }
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
    {\addcomma\space}{}
  }
}


This is probably best done with data annotations analogous to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468623/35864 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/680196/35864 (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304968/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/561061/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/349570/35864)

That's brilliant and exactly what I need. I've voted to close this question as a duplicate.

Great! Thanks for the feedback. Glad it works for you.
